# how to update another field on admin django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

## models.py

Good night friends, I would like to know if there is a possibility that every time I register a new move, the django administrator checks what is a 'hydrographic region' and adds the value that is entering with the 'balance_box'.

```
class Movement(models.Model):

    TYPE_MOVE = (
        ('1', 'Receita'),
        ('2', 'Despesa'),
    )

    regiao_hidrografica = models.ForeignKey(RegiaoHidrografica, verbose_name="Região Hidrografica", null=False)
    origem = models.ForeignKey(Origem, verbose_name="Origem", null=False)
    finalidade_recurso = models.ForeignKey(FinalidadeRecursos, verbose_name="Finalidade de Recursos", null=True)
    descricao = models.TextField("Descrição", null=True)
    valor = MoneyField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, default_currency='BRL')
    data_refencia = MonthField("Data de Referencia", help_text="Informe mês e ano")
    # data_refencia = models.DateField("Data de Referencia", null=True, blank=True, default=None)
    tipo_movimento = models.CharField(max_length=1, default=1, choices=TYPE_MOVE)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.descricao

    def update_total_valor(self):
        total = 0
        self.movimento_set:
            total += mov.valor
        self.saldo_caixa = total
        self.save()


class RegiaoHidrografica(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField("Nome", max_length=100, null=False)
    sigla = models.CharField("Sigla", max_length=10, null=True)
    taxa_inea = models.IntegerField(default=10, null=True)
    taxa_trans = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=True)
    saldo_caixa = MoneyField('Saldo em caixa estimado', max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, null=True, default=0, default_currency='BRL')
    saldo_cc = MoneyField('Saldo em conta estimado', max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, null=True, default=0, default_currency='BRL') 
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

I tried something like this, create this method in the 'class MovimentoAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin)', but it did not work.

## admin.py

```
def save_formset(self, request, form, formset, change):
        instances = formset.save(commit=False)
        for instance in instances:
            instance.save()
        formset.save_m2m()
        instance.RegiaoHidrografica.update_total_valor()
```

Would anyone have a hint how I could do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds to me like you need [Django Signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/signals/).

You can register a listener on the `post_save` signal for your model `Movement`. The listener then would check for changes (it can also detect object creation with the parameter `created`) and react accordingly.

However, this would not only apply to Django Administrator but rather to all positions in your code where a `Movement` object got created. If you only create those objects via the admin site you are fine. 
 Otherwise, consider overwriting the Django `ModelAdmin.save_model` method:
[Example in Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.save_model). This method also provides you with the ability to detect object creation as well.

If you really want to use the `save_formset` method instead, check your code. `update_total_valor` is defined in and for class `Movement` and not `RegiaoHidrografica` according to your snippet, the method in *admin.py* is defined on `Movement` (which is fine, but then your access to `RegiaoHidrografica` looks wrong to me, since you are trying to access a class name instead of the model property).

I recommend to work with Django signals here, they provide a ton of comfort (but also have a trade-off: Added processing time when saving an object...